# ¿Por qué estos for anidados solicitan más datos de los que el for dice?

Tags: c++, dev-c++, visual-c++

¿como están? Soy nueva en c++ y estoy aprendiendo todo desde el inicio así que tal vez a algunos se les haga una pregunta muy fácil u obvia pero yo estoy comenzando.

Esta pregunta ya la había hecho, pero como la consulta en si ya me la evacuaron, hago otra pregunta nueva porque ahora no entiendo el evento que sucede.

Estoy haciendo un programa sencillo pero no entiendo por qué estos for me solicitan los datos 8 veces cuando deberían hacerlo solo 2 veces por cada for, en total 4 veces. ¿Me explicarían por qué sucede esto?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main (){

    int acumulador1, acumulador2;
     acumulador1=0;
     acumulador2=0;

     for(int i=1; i<=2;i++){
        for(int j=1; j<=2;j++){

           int primernumero,segundonumero;

           cout<<"Ingrese el primer numero :"<<i<<endl;
           cin>>primernumero;
           cout<<"Ingrese el segundo numero :"<<j<<endl;
           cin>>segundonumero;

           acumulador1 = acumulador1+primernumero;
           acumulador2 = acumulador2+segundonumero;
        }

    }

    cout<<"El resultado del acumulador 1 es :"<<acumulador1<<endl;
    cout<<"El resultado del acumulador 2 es :"<<acumulador2<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**El codigo deberia hacer esto**

Ingrese el primer numero :" 3

Ingrese el segundo numero :" 2

Ingrese el primer numero :" 3

Ingrese el segundo numero :" 2

El resultado del acumulador 1 es : 6

El resultado del acumulador 2 es : 4

**esto es lo que debería hacer el programa pero no entiendo como hacerlo**

Answer (score 0):

El bucle externo va de `1` a `2`, el bucle interno va de `1` a `2` tantas veces como se recorra el bucle externo, así que en la primera vuelta del bucle externo el interno se recorrerá dos veces y en la segunda vuelta del bucle externo el interno se recorrerá dos veces más.

Total de iteraciones: cuatro, no ocho. Te parece ocho porque pides dos datos en cada vuelta: dos datos por cuatro vueltas, son ocho datos.

Comment: y como aria para tener esa misma sintaxis pero pidiendo solo 2 datos por cada for que al final eso es lo que busco pero no se como hacerlo

Answer (score 0):

Estas trabajando con bucles anidados, es decir que el primer ciclo *for* (el de la i) se ejecuta dos veces, y el segundo ciclo *for* ( el de la j) se ejecuta dos veces por cada vez que se ejecute el primer ciclo *for* y dentro del segundo ciclo se hacen dos preguntas: por tanto 2 * 2 * 2 = 8

```
for(int i=1; i<=2;i++){
    for(int j=1; j<=2;j++){
       cout<<"Ingrese el primer numero :"<<i<<endl;
       cout<<"Ingrese el segundo numero :"<<j<<endl;
```

El resultado lo puedes ver claramente en la salida que ofrece tu programa

Ingrese el primer numero :1  <- i vale uno

Ingrese el segundo numero :1 <- j vale uno también

Ingrese el primer numero :1 <- i sigue valiendo uno, es el primer ciclo de i

Ingrese el segundo numero :2 <- j vale 2, y con este termina su ciclo

Ingrese el primer numero :2 <- i vale 2, esta en su segundo ciclo ya

Ingrese el segundo numero :1 <- j vale 1 Comenzó de nuevo dentro de la segunda iteración del primer ciclo

Ingrese el primer numero :2 <- i sigue valiendo 2

Ingrese el segundo numero :2 <- finalmente j vale 2 y termina su ciclo

Seria algo así:

```
i = 1
   j = 1
     numero 1
     numero 2
   j = 2
     numero 1
     numero 2
i = 2
   j = 1
     numero 1
     numero 2
   j = 2
     numero 1
     numero 2
```

Comment: y como aria para poder solicitar solo 2 veces por cada for los datos, porque si esas interaciones son asi por los recorridos como podria hacer para solicitar 4 veces el dato, dos por cada for?

Comment: si quisiera hacerlo como digo entonces tendria que hacer 4 for diferentes para pedir 2 veces un dato por separado y otros 2 datos por separado?

Comment: Sugiero que escribas como debe ser el enunciado de lo que quieres: para poder entender que es lo que necesitas, luego para mayor aclaracion, coloca el ejemplo de como sería la salida que esperas encontrar cuando tu programa corra, ahora simplemente es imposible saber que es lo que quieres